# JavaScript create new element with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I try to make a ToDoList. It should create new ToDo's automatically.

So I created an function that should do this automatically, but it doesn't work, I think it's a small mistake.

I hope someone is able to help me.

Little glossary to understand my code:

- "Eintrag" is a new ToDo
- Ja = Yes
- Nein = No
- Erledigt = Done
- Wichtig = Important
- Datum = date
- Aufgabe = task

Here is my code

```js
var eintrag1 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag2 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden1",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag3 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden2",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag4 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden3",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag5 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden4",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag6 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden5",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag7 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden6",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag8 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden7",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag9 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden8",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag10 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Bade9n",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag12 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden10",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag13 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden11",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag14 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden12",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag15 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden13",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag16 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden14",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag17 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden15",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag18 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden16",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag19 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden17",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag20 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden18",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};
var eintrag21 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden19",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag22 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden20",
  erledigt: "ja",
  wichtig: "nein"
};
var eintrag23 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden21",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};

var e = document.querySelector("p");
var checked = "";
var checkede = "";
var check = function(wert) {
  if (wert === "ja") {
    return ("checked");
  }
}
var auto = function() {
  for (var i = 1; i < 23; i++) {
    var neuein = "eintrag" + i.toString();
    var dat = neuein + ".Datum";
    var auf = neuein + ".Aufgabe";
    var erl = neuein + ".erledigt";
    var wich = neuein + ".wichtig";


    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + ' <p>  ' +
      ' <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value = ' + dat + '> ' +
      ' <input type="text" value=' + auf + '>' +
      ' Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" ' + check(erl) + ' >' +
      ' Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig"  ' + check(wich) + ' > ' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" id="edit"> ' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Speichern" id="save">' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Löschen" id="delete"> ' +
      ' </p>';

  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value="Datum">
    <input type="text"> Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" value="Erledigt"> Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig" value="Wichtig">
    <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" id="edit">
    <input type="button" value="Speichern" id="save">
    <input type="button" value="Löschen" id="delete">

  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Liste Speichern" id="savelist">
    <input type="button" value="Exportieren" id="export">
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: IDs should be **unique** in a single document - duplicate IDs in one document is **invalid HTML**, you might consider fixing that

Comment: You are not calling the `auto()` function

Comment: The first lines in your for loop don't work. If you keep the `var eintrag1` scheme (I'd use an array instead), you need `var neuein = window["eintrag" + i];` and  `var dat = neuein.Datum;` and so on.

Comment: Live example code using current JS: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/v21bd6yc/ (remove edit button since form is editable already)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your items into an array:

```
var eintrage = [
    {Datum:"31.11.12", Aufgabe:"Baden" ,erledigt:"nein" ,wichtig:"ja"}, //array items are seperated by a comma
    {Datum:"31.11.12", Aufgabe:"Baden1" ,erledigt:"nein" ,wichtig:"nein"},
    ...
];
```

Them you can loop through your array like so:

```
var auto = function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < eintrage.length; i++) { //eintrage.length equals the length of the array (how many items there are)
        var neuein = eintrage[i]; //you can access an index of an array like so: array[index]
        var dat = neuein.Datum; //you can acces methods of objects like so: object.method
        var auf = neuein.Aufgab;
        var erl = neuein.erledigt;
        var wich = neuein.wichtig; 

        ...
```

Finally don't forget to call your function:

```
auto();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 closing tags  and a couple of missing html tags, so i assume this is not all the code.

If you set a breakpoint in the function, if it does not hit the breakpoint you should check the place where you actually call it (since i cant see it in the code) and secondly remove the

tags in your script. Since you are already adding the code to a

tag and nesting

tags isnt possible.
The second is most likely the reason it isnt working. so;

change

```
 e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + ' <p>  ' +
                               ' <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value = '+ dat +'> ' +
                               ' <input type="text" value='+ auf +'>' +
                               ' Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" ' + check(erl) + ' >' +
                               ' Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig"  ' + check(wich) + ' > ' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" id="edit"> ' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Speichern" id="save">' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Löschen" id="delete"> ' +
                               ' </p>';
```

To:

```
 e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML + 
                               ' <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value = '+ dat +'> ' +
                               ' <input type="text" value='+ auf +'>' +
                               ' Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" ' + check(erl) + ' >' +
                               ' Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig"  ' + check(wich) + ' > ' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" id="edit"> ' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Speichern" id="save">' +
                               ' <input type="button" value="Löschen" id="delete"> ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`"eintrag1"` (string) isn’t the same as `eintrag1` (variable name), and there’s no good way to get the variable from the string. To store a sequence of things, use an array, not numbered variables.

```
var eintragen = [{
    Datum: "31.11.12",
    Aufgabe: "Baden"
},{
    Datum: "31.11.12",
    Aufgabe: "Baden1"
}]

for ( var i = 0; i < eintragen.length; i++ ) {
    var neuein = eintragen[ i ]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version - I just wanted to optimise the code for you

Note the class instead of ID and the use of dot notation. You can do 
`neuein["Datum"]` instead of neuein.Datum

Using jQuery you could also easily use clone instead of creating the row by concatenation

```js
var eintrag = [{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden1", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden2", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden3", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden4", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden5", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden6", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden7", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden8", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Bade9n", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden10", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden11", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden12", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden13", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden14", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden15", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden16", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden17", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden18", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden19", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden20", erledigt: "ja", wichtig: "nein"},{ Datum: "31.11.12", Aufgabe: "Baden21", erledigt: "nein", wichtig: "ja"}]

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  var e = [];

  for (var i = 1, n= eintrag.length; i < n; i++) {
    var neuein = eintrag[i];
    var dat  = neuein.Datum;
    var auf  = neuein.Aufgabe;
    var erl  = neuein.erledigt==="ja"?" checked":"";
    var wich = neuein.wichtig ==="ja"?" checked":"";


    e.push(' <p>  ' +
      ' <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value = ' + dat + '> ' +
      ' <input type="text" value=' + auf + '>' +
      ' Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" ' + erl + ' >' +
      ' Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig"  '  + wich + ' > ' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" class="edit"> ' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Speichern" class="save">' +
      ' <input type="button" value="Löschen" class="delete"> ' +
      ' </p>');
  }
  document.querySelector("p").innerHTML += e.join("");
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Datum" value="Datum">
    <input type="text"> Erledigt <input type="checkbox" name="erledigt" value="Erledigt"> Wichtig <input type="checkbox" name="Wichtig" value="Wichtig">
    <input type="button" value="Bearbeiten" class="edit">
    <input type="button" value="Speichern" class="save">
    <input type="button" value="Löschen" class="delete">

  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Liste Speichern" id="savelist">
    <input type="button" value="Exportieren" id="export">
  </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems in your script.

1.You are not calling the auto() function.

2.In your auto function you have mentioned `var neuein = "eintrag" + i.toString();var dat = neuein + ".Datum";`, I believe here you want to access the values of the declared Objects say `var eintrag1 = {
  Datum: "31.11.12",
  Aufgabe: "Baden",
  erledigt: "nein",
  wichtig: "ja"
};`
but your `var dat` will **simply contain the string** `eintrag1.Datum`  and not a reference to the Object value `eintrag1.Datum which is 31.11.12`

To achieve what you intended you have to use `var dat = eval(neuein)["Datum"]`

Check this link out and let us know if this is what you intented to happen https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hcvj1g